# Passing through symbols to twitter intent

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api, twitter

Creating a random quote generator with Twitter functionality.

You click the button to generate a quote from an API, quote appears and the user has the option if they wish to tweet it.

My problem is that I don't know how to pass through symbols such as apostrophes and dashes to URL's without the characters being converted to &sdfkj; (or whatever the heck it is).

Code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Random Quote Generator</title>
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Random Quotes Rewritten</h1>
    <p>Would you like a random sentence to send to someone or incorporate in your project? Press the button below!</p>
    <div class="quotearea">

    </div>
    <button id="newquote">New quote</button>
    <button class="tweetquote"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   Tweet Quote</button>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var quoteObj;
var quoteContent;
var quoteTitle;

$("#newquote").click(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=30&jsonp=mycallback", function(a) {
    $(".quotearea").empty();
    $(".quotearea").addClass("border");
    quote = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)];
    quoteContent = quote.content;
    quoteTitle = quote.title;
    $(".quotearea").append(quoteContent + " " + quoteTitle);
    $('.tweetquote:hidden').show();
  });
});

$('.tweetquote').click(function() {
  window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + quoteContent + quoteTitle);
});
```

The randomly generated quote:
https://i.gyazo.com/21757e1bc9a5fe4040a21fb2b9cc9625.png

The quote passed into Twitter intent (without URIEncoding):
https://i.gyazo.com/44e7c9922255db19f6abd4de6a5cb4e6.png

As you can see the generated quote just cuts off. So I searched the web and found encodeURIComponent(), seemed like a good option.

But now, the quote looks odd.

https://i.gyazo.com/ff78cd907d25a88c3c8ca20533b60d6c.png

Is there a function or approach I could use to help me with this?

Thanks,
James.